# psycopg2 set PRIMARY KEY from tuple with placeholder

Tags: python, psycopg2

How can I set a primary key in psycopg2 from a tuple of values being looped in from a tuple?

for example i have my tuple

```
meetattrs = ('id', 'venue', 'date', 'rail', 'weather', 'trackcondition')
```

and then I want to create the table and extract and insert values. From the meetattrs I wish to set id as the primary key.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("")
with conn, conn.cursor() as cur:
        # First, create tables.
    cur.execute("drop table if exists meetings, races, horses")
    cur.execute("create table meetings (id integer PRIMARY KEY, " +
                ", ".join("%s varchar" % fld for fld in meetattrs)
                + ")")
```

This however creates this error, unsure how to resolve.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "racemeeting.py", line 56, in <module>
    + ")")
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "id" specified more than once
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current sql query after the `join` is performed and the placeholders take their values is:

```
'create table meetings (id integer PRIMARY KEY, id varchar, venue varchar, date varchar, rail varchar, weather varchar, trackcondition varchar)'
```

`id` is specified twice.

You can build your query in a much cleaner way:

```
query_params = " %s integer PRIMARY KEY" + ", %s varchar" * (len(meetattrs) - 1)
```

And your SQL statement becomes:

```
"create table meetings (" + query_params % meetattrs + ")"
```

After the insertion of placeholder values:

```
'create table meetings (id integer PRIMARY KEY, venue varchar, date varchar, rail varchar, weather varchar, trackcondition varchar)'
```

Be sure your tuple always has its first item as `id`

Answer (score 1):

In that kind of problem, you should first try to build and control the sql string.

```
("create table meetings (id integer PRIMARY KEY, " +
            ", ".join("%s varchar" % fld for fld in meetattrs)
            + ")")
```

gives:

```
'create table meetings (id integer PRIMARY KEY, id varchar, venue varchar, date varchar, rail varchar, weather varchar, trackconditionvarchar)'
```

effectively duplicating `id` column.

The solution is then trivial: remove first identifier from `meetattrs`:

```
cur.execute("create table meetings (id integer PRIMARY KEY, " +
            ", ".join("%s varchar" % fld for fld in meetattrs[1:])
            + ")")
```

Alternatively if you cannot be sure that the primary key if the first element:

```
cur.execute("create table meetings (id integer PRIMARY KEY, " +
            ", ".join("%s varchar" % fld for fld in meetattrs if fld != 'id')
            + ")")
```